# can anybody post tutorial links for jtidy to convert xhtml to xml

Tags: java, jtidy

can anybody give sample program for converting xhtml doc to xml using jtidy in java.

or otherwise post the tutorial link for using jtidy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [these examples](http://jtidy.homelinux.net/jtidyservlet-webapp/) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

A XHTML document is already a XML document, so basically you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple code for this;

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setMakeClean(true);
tidy.setXmlOut( true);

URL url = new URL("url_string_here");

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("outXHTML.xml");   

Document doc = tidy.parseDOM( url.openStream(), fileOutputStream);
```

Hope this helps.